# WordPress Redirect Trouble

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm hoping someone could explain a way to use a variable within the wp_redirect() function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Answer (score 0):

There are two variables:

```
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
```

$location is the absolute URI which the user will be redirected to.

$status is the status code to use (eg, 301). Default is 302 (so you can leave it blank if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not storing value of url and even not getting in **add_to_cart_redirect** function.Try below code

```
//* Add/Display Fields
  add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data',    'rv_woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
 function rv_woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
global $post_id;
global $woocommerce, $post;
echo '<div class="options_group">';
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'          => '_rv_woo_product_custom_redirect_url', 
        'label'       => __( 'Redirect on Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => 'http://',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter a URL to redirect the user to after this product is added to the cart.', 'woocommerce' ) ,
        'value' => get_post_meta($post_id,'c',true)
    )
);
echo '</div>';
}

//* Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta',  'rv_woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function rv_woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){ 
$rv_woo_redirect_url = get_post_meta($post_id,'c',true);
if( !empty( $rv_woo_redirect_url ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'c', esc_url( $rv_woo_redirect_url ) );
}
}
 add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_elsewhere');
 function redirect_elsewhere() {  
global $woocommerce, $post;
$product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );
$rv_woo_redirect_url = get_post_meta($product_id,'c',true);
if( !empty( $rv_woo_redirect_url ) ) {
      wp_redirect( $rv_woo_redirect_url );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhumi! You helped me a ton and I really really appreciate you taking the time to give me the solution. Best regards.